# Matlab for loops: using vector in a loop twice

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I have a small problem regarding loops with a matlab simple script.

I have a structure/table with for example 13 fields. I want to name differently 3 of those fields for every 6 field. That's example:

> 1. qwert
> 2. qwert
> 3. qwert
> 4. something_else
> 5. something_else
> 6. qwert
> 7. qwert
> 8. qwert
> 9. something_else
> 10. something_else
> 11. qwert
> 12. qwert
> 13. qwert ...

That's my code, but it doesn't work well.

```
v = (1:6:13);
    for i = v:1:3
    table(i).type = 'qwert';
    end
```

I know that Matlab doesn't want to use this 'v' vector in for loop, instead it wants to have a scalar. How can I solve this?

Thank you very much in advance,
Mary

Answer (score 0):

A simple way:

```
v = (1:5:13);
for i = v
    for j=0:2
        table(i+j).type = 'qwert';
    end
end
```

Note that to get your described result, you have to use a steplength of 5... since this is every 5th field, not every 6th.